# Are NAND Gate Pinouts a Standard?

Tags: digital-logic

I have this really old NAND gate that I need to replace.

[image: Picture]

As you will see, [the datasheet](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/76789/MICROSEMI/TSC302.html) is worthless and it is the only one that I can find.  This is my first experience using a NAND gate (I starting classes for embedded micro controllers and electronics, after getting interested in arduino).

I know there is probably no way to tell me definitely, but I found [74ACT1100](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/405/scas002a-126039.pdf) on Mouser.  If I just get one of these (matched by mouser search for same number of pins) will it be suitable?

Is this pinout common among all that make these chips?  The datasheet is so blurred and in bad shape I can't tell what I'm looking at.  All of the TI chips seem to have this same pinout (only TI results returned from my Mouser search).

Comment: Those gates don't look *quite* like a modern one; I wouldn't try to replace it with anything other than the same chip unless you can rework the circuit.

Comment: Some more info may be helpful.  What is the reason to replace the chip? Do you know for sure it's not working?  Is that chip shown in the photo the original?    The "8945" could be a date code - week 45 of year '89.  But that PC board just looks older, based on years of experience looking at electronics. That's just my intuition; depending on who made that and what kind of device it is, maybe that means nothing. Or maybe that's not the original chip.

Comment: Finally, can the device be powered up so you can measure voltages at the pins, or at least determine the power supply voltage used?   This could help pin down the logic family or which variation of a substitute chip would be best suited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another [datasheet](http://www.digchip.com/data/000/0-496-302aj.pdf) found in a minute using Google is much more readable.

And it's clear that none of the 74 series parts is a suitable replacement.
[One of the links](http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets_pdf/T/S/C/3/TSC302.shtml) suggested that Microsemi may have taken over manufacture so it might be worthwhile contacting them.

I found one for sale [here](http://www.bbhparts.com/IC-302-AJ-CJ-QUAD-POWER-NAND-GATE-93E352534.htm) - probably cheaper than developing a replacement solution.

Comment: Or just use the datasheet Brian found and stick some discretes onto a perf board if your time is worth less than $50 to get the replacement part. This family (HiNIL = High Noise Immunity Logic) was promoted for used in industrial environments where its large noise immunity (volts not hundreds of mV) and heavy output current capability (65mA) was a real advantage. There is no direct substitute- we mostly learned to make the fussy circuits immune to EMI rather than using a special logic family that was inherently rugged.

Answer (score 1):

I had no trouble finding a reasonable (for that time) datasheet. The TSC301 seems to be a diode-transistor logic gate with open collector output, for up to 15V power, and with 15 mA drive capability. Two of the gates have a pin that bypasses the diodes (connects directly to the base of the input stage).

These features are so unlike the current logic families that you should not blindly substitute anything but the same type, even when the pinouts match (which is not likely, because of the extra bypass input pin).

If you can analyze your circuit you might be able to figure out which features of this chip are really used, which might enable you to find a substitute. But probably with a different pinbout.